# Object detection- How to re-apply manipulated pixels within co-ordinates to the original image to highlight RoI

Tags: python, image, opencv, object-detection

I have a set of coordinates for an RGB image (1920 x 1080) stored as a list of list which is RoI (region of interests) as follows

```
[[1538, 234, 1626, 313],
[421, 231, 472, 288],
[918, 199, 988, 270],
[802, 0, 963, 114],
[1732, 0, 1909, 108]]
```

I then apply the following conditions to change specific pixel values within the co-ordinates in the list of the list above only to highlight these RoIs by changing the pixels into white and black.

```
for coords in list_of_coords:

            roi = orig[coords[1]:coords[3], coords[0]:coords[2]]

            roi [(roi > 200)] = 0
            roi [(roi < 200)] = 255
```

How can I now take these new modified pixel values and apply them on top of the original image with a degree of transparency? Ideally, the rest of the image will be the same whilst the values within these coordinates will have a transparent mask on top of them.

Here is an example of how the desired output should look like. I have taken this from Mask RCNN, where within the rectangle coordinates, a slight shade of blue is added to highlight the RoI. The rectangle boxes are represented with the list of list above, and the shade of blue is the manipulation from the conditions mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some exemplary input and output - maybe manually edited? There's some room for interpretation at the moment.

Comment: @HansHirse please let me know if the updated question is sufficient enough in providing the examples requested

Comment: But what kind of mask are you setting up by subtracting the red and green channels? `new_image` is basically some "black-white pattern". Or is `new_image` the actual mask? Then, what kind of colors do you want to add? Can you please provide some real-world examples - especially where this "red/green thing" becomes more clear? In general, you'll need alpha blending as mentioned below. But I'm still struggling to understand what to actually blend.

Comment: @HansHirse I updated my question, I am trying to do the equivalent of MaskRCNN. This is a real-world example where you have multiple objects in an image detected by the rectangles above, I apply the manipulation to the pixel, and I want to reapply those into the original image to highlight the RoIs.

Comment: @HansHirse I removed the b,g,r subtraction since it is not necessary! The question is how to re-apply manipulated pixels to the original image :) that's all. The subtraction was extra information to show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure, if I fully understood, what you want to achieve, but here's my attempt to answer your question:

Basically, for each set of coordinates, you'd need to do the following:

1. Get a ROI cutout of your original image. (You already have that.)
2. Generate some binary mask (with respect to some metric or whatever information you have) to indicate which part inside the ROI you want to manipulate, e.g. the car shown in your image. In my code below, I chose to mask any pixels with some high blue channel value.
3. Generate a blend image with the same size of the ROI and fill all pixels with a solid color with respect to the generated mask. In my code below, I chose to set up some solid green.
4. Use OpenCV's [`addWeighted`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gafafb2513349db3bcff51f54ee5592a19) method for the alpha blending.
5. Copy back the updated ROI cutout to your original image.

Here's the final output for my example image and coordinates:

[image: Final output]

That's my code:

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load image
orig = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
orig_back = orig.copy()

# Set up list of list of coordinates (i.e. rectangular ROIs)
list_of_coords = [[90, 0, 260, 30],
                  [60, 180, 100, 250],
                  [300, 300, 380, 370]]

# Set up alpha for alpha blending
alpha = 0.5

for coords in list_of_coords:

    # Get ROI cutout of image
    roi = orig_back[coords[1]:coords[3], coords[0]:coords[2]]
    roi_back = roi.copy()

    # Generate some mask; examplary here: Mask anything with some high
    # blue channel value
    mask = roi[:, :, 0] > 172

    # Generate blend image; exemplary here: Blend with solid green
    blend = np.zeros_like(roi)
    blend[mask, 1] = 255

    # Alpha blending original image with blend image
    roi[mask, :] = cv2.addWeighted(roi[mask, :], alpha,
                                   blend[mask, :], 1 - alpha,
                                   0)

    # Copy updated ROI cutout back to image
    orig[coords[1]:coords[3], coords[0]:coords[2]] = roi

    # Add rectangle to image for location
    orig = cv2.rectangle(orig,
                         (coords[0], coords[1]),
                         (coords[2], coords[3]),
                         (0, 255, 0),
                         2)

    # Some visualization output for better understanding
    plt.figure(0, figsize=(16, 8))
    plt.subplot(221)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(roi_back, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title('ROI cutout of image')
    plt.subplot(222)
    plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
    plt.title('Masked portion of ROI with high blue channel value')
    plt.subplot(223)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(blend, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title('Blend image, solid green')
    plt.subplot(224)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title('Updated ROI cutout of image')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


# Final output
cv2.imshow('Original image with updates and rectangles', orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And, here's the additional visualization for the first ROI:

[image: Additional visualization]

Hopefully, that's what you're looking for!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
Matplotlib:  3.3.1
NumPy:       1.19.1
OpenCV:      4.4.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you for the fantastic and detailed explanation. I modified your answer a bit to fit my solution, and I leave it here for the users of the future.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful. Nevertheless, please add your suggested edit to your question or post an own answer, since your edit conflicts with my original intent. That's common practice here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for is `alpha blending`.
If you have the two images (of the same size) that you gave in description (let's call them `img` and `annotation`), you can do :

```
alpha = 0.5 
# How much you want img to be opaque, alpha = 1 leads to your result being img,
# alpha = 0 to result==annotation
# with alpha = 0.5, you will get a blending with each image have the same 
# importance
result = cv2.addWeighted(img, alpha, annotation, 1-alpha, 0)
```

You can find some explanation about of the function [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-numpy-alpha-blend-mask/).

Now, if your images are not of the same size, you need to resize them *before* blending them (I would resize the smaller one to get the same size as the bigger one), so it should look something like this :

```
width = img.shape[1]
height = img.shape[0]
dim = (width, height)
annotation = cv2.resize(annotation, dim)
```

Comment: thank you for introducing this, I think there might be an intermediate step missing between what you mention above and where I stopped in the question which is manipulating individual pixels part. Since the image is 1920 x 1080, I cannot blend co-ordinates which are 100 x 80, and other cases 300 x 200 directly. I think there should a template 1920 x 1080 which is a mask of the pixel manipulations applied that I can apply on top of the image using the method you mention above.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully, it is clearer. I apologize for all the confusion. There are multiple objects within the same image highlighted by the coordinates in the list of lists above. If I would to `cv2.resize` each individual co-ordinates, then that would be incorrect because one coordinate would stretch over the whole image instead of its respective size within the image. Therefore, the blending should be applied to each set of co-ordinates individually. Please check the last image I added to the question.